# How using sql select get result with max value by one columns in a set of records?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this data in a table.

```
date       | name        | code
2020-01-01 | category1   | 0
2020-01-02 | category1   | 1
2020-01-03 | category1   | 2
2020-01-04 | category1   | 3
2020-01-05 | category1   | 0
2020-01-06 | category1   | 1
2020-01-07 | category1   | 2
2020-01-08 | category1   | 0
2020-01-01 | category2   | 0
2020-01-02 | category2   | 0
2020-01-03 | category2   | 1
2020-01-04 | category2   | 0
2020-01-05 | category2   | 1
2020-01-06 | category2   | 2
2020-01-07 | category2   | 0
2020-01-08 | category2   | 1
......
```

Column code in the set is increased by 1.

Need to get records where one column have a max value in a set of records. Result for my example must be:

```
date       | name        | code
2020-01-04 | category1   | 3
2020-01-07 | category1   | 2
2020-01-03 | category2   | 1
2020-01-06 | category2   | 2
2020-01-08 | category2   | 1
......
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select date, name, code
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        lead(code) over(partition by name order by date) lead_code
    from mytable t
) t 
where not code <= lead_code
```

For your sample data, [this produces](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7d8fbbe521ad7232059f7f77305b1e7d):

```
date       | name      | code
:--------- | :-------- | ---:
2020-01-04 | category1 |    3
2020-01-07 | category1 |    2
2020-01-03 | category2 |    1
2020-01-06 | category2 |    2
```

Comment: Must be `WHERE code > lead_code OR lead_code IS NULL`.

Comment: Pay attention - (2020-01-01, category2) which is formally a group of single record is not listed.

Comment: @Akina: this seems to produce *almost* the expected results (apart from the last record, which is not listed in my output). `WHERE code > lead_code OR lead_code IS NULL` produces [something a bit different](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7de65efc0d6e3f584c0f8ea4625c27f9).

Comment: You forget that a "set" have the same `name`.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH cte AS (
SELECT date, 
       name, 
       code, 
       LEAD(code) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date) next_code,
       LEAD(name) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date) next_name
FROM source_table
)
SELECT date, name, code
FROM cte
WHERE (    name = next_name 
        OR next_name IS NULL )
  AND (    code > next_code
        OR next_code IS NULL )  
  AND code > 0;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9bd42192da288e6dbe9944ab8d1420f4).

PS. Thanks to [GMB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10676716/gmb) - the base for a fiddle was stolen from his answer.

Comment: Seem need to have installed MYSQL ver.8 for your script to working

Comment: @user2702614 Of course. The version is not specified in a question - this means that the most recent version is used.